# LightSwitch Lists Within Lists

Tags: lightswitch-2012

I have a browse screen in LightSwitch Html that lists Requests.
Each of these Requests contains a list of People.
This is a many to many relationship between People and Requests, done using a RequestPerson table.

On the screen I would like to display each Request line with a list of its People.

Request 1

```
     Person1
     Person3
```

Request 2

```
     Person2
     Person3
```

I tried adding a data item of People to the screen, by clicking the addPeople link in the Request data item, and adding it to each Request's row in the list, but this simply creates duplicate lists of the People in the selected row. I want each People list to be a list of People in the Request it belongs to.

Can anyone make any suggestions as to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/506ea3fc-f352-4858-9983-83f6b865129a/lists-in-lists?prof=required

Needs ajax calls for each sub-list, but it works.